# Can async and defer be used in the same script tags HTML?

Tags: html

To elaborate, do both attributes still run if I do the following: `<script async defer src="script.js></script>`?

Comment: Or do they cancel each other out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question **Yes**

You can add both async and defer in the same script tag.
However it doesn't cancel out. The second one acts as a fallback if the first is unavailable.

> The defer attribute may be specified even if the async attribute is specified, to cause legacy Web browsers that only support defer (and not async) to fall back to the defer behavior instead of the synchronous blocking behavior that is the default.

Since both attributes are boolean you don't have to assign any value.